# How to check checkboxes after submiting as same as previously checked?

Tags: javascript, checkbox, asp.net-core-mvc

case is ,
First I checked few check box and than submit it , even after clicking on submit the checkbox should be checked as previously selected.
Please help me in achieving it.
For example have a look at Custom filter in stack overflow
this is my HTML code:

```
<form asp-controller="Student" asp-action="FilterStu">
                    <div class="dropdown">
                        <div class="selectBox" onclick="showCheckboxes()">
                            <select class="btn btn-outline-secondary">
                                <option style="color:darkturquoise">
                                    Filter
                                </option>
                            </select>
                            <div class="overSelect"></div>
                        </div>
                        <div id="checkboxes" class="dropdown-content" >
                            <ul>
                                <label clasenter image description heres="labelclass" style="color:cornflowerblue"><u><i class="bi bi-book-half"></i>Courses</u></label>
                                <li>
                                    <input class="cb" name="searchString1" type="checkbox" id="Int" value="Java" />&nbsp;&nbsp;Java
                                </li>
                                <li>
                                    <input name="searchString2" type="checkbox" id="Int" value="C+" />&nbsp;&nbsp;C++
                                </li>
                                <li>
                                    <input name="searchString3" type="checkbox" id="Int" value="Python" />&nbsp;&nbsp;Python
                                </li>
                                <label style="color:cornflowerblue"><i class="bi bi-people"></i> <u>Gender</u></label>
                                <li>
                                    <input name="gender" type="checkbox" id="Int" value="Male" />&nbsp;&nbsp;Male
                                </li>
                                <li>
                                    <input name="gender" type="checkbox" id="Int" value="Female" />&nbsp;&nbsp;Female
                                </li>
                                <label style="color:cornflowerblue"><i class="bi bi-sort-alpha-down"></i><u>Sorting</u></label>
                                <li>
                                    <input name="sortByAz" type="checkbox" id="Int" value="sort" />&nbsp;&nbsp;Sort by A-Z
                                </li>
                                <li>
                                    <input name="sortByZa" type="checkbox" id="Int" value="sort" />&nbsp;&nbsp;Sort by Z-A
                                </li>
                                </p>
                                <button class="btn btn-outline-success my-2 my-sm-0" type="submit"><i class="bi bi-search"></i>&nbsp;&nbsp;</button>
                                <button class="btn btn-outline-warning" type="submit" asp-action="Index" asp-controller="Student"><i class="bi bi-house"></i>Clear</button>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </form>
```

I tried creating arrays of checked items and Creating Viewbag for each

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you want is after the form is submitted and the page is returned, checkbox should be checked as previously selected？ If i don't misunderstand your case, You can try this code:

BTW, Why you set different names to Courses and Sorting options? For testing purposes, I set them both to the same name, so I only need one parameter to accept, of course you can leave it as is.

```
    <label clasenter image description heres="labelclass" style="color:cornflowerblue"><u><i class="bi bi-book-half"></i>Courses</u></label>
    <li>
        <input class="cb" name="searchString" type="checkbox" id="Int" value="Java" />&nbsp;&nbsp;Java
   </li>
   <li>
        <input name="searchString" type="checkbox" id="Int" value="C+" />&nbsp;&nbsp;C++
    </li>
    <li>                            
        <input name="searchString" type="checkbox" id="Int" value="Python" />&nbsp;&nbsp;Python
    </li>

........

<label style="color:cornflowerblue"><i class="bi bi-sort-alpha-down"></i><u>Sorting</u></label>
<li>
     <input name="sort" type="checkbox" id="Int" value="sortByAz" />&nbsp;&nbsp;Sort by A-Z
</li>
<li>                                
     <input name="sort" type="checkbox" id="Int" value="sortByZa"  />&nbsp;&nbsp;Sort by Z-A
</li>
```

I set viewbag in backend:

```
[HttpPost]
        public IActionResult Privacy(string searchString,string gender,string sort)
        {
            ViewBag.SearchString = searchString;
            ViewBag.gender = gender;
            ViewBag.sort = sort;    

            //.....other code......
           
            return View();
        }
```

In the View, I set hidden input to receive `viewbag` and use js to add checked attribute:

```
                <input type="hidden" id="TestA" value="@ViewBag.SearchString"/>
                <input type="hidden" id="TestB" value="@ViewBag.gender"/>
                <input type="hidden" id="TestC" value="@ViewBag.sort"/>

                <script>
                    var searchString =  document.querySelectorAll('[name="searchString"],[name="gender"],[name="sort"]');
                    
                    for (let i = 0; i < searchString.length; ++i) {
                        if(searchString[i].value == document.getElementById("TestA").value || searchString[i].value == document.getElementById("TestB").value || searchString[i].value == document.getElementById("TestC").value)
                        {
                            searchString[i].setAttribute("checked", "checked");
                        }
                    }
                </script>
```

Demo:

[image]

Comment: Hi @Shrenik YD, If this answer can help you solve your issue, can you mark it as the answer? Thank you so much.